# Перенос проекта на Android/IOS

Tags: android, unity3d, ios

Есть проект Unity под Win, нужно перенести на Android/IOS. Какие есть основные отличия написания кода под win и под мобильные платформы? Нужно ли что-то переписывать в коде или все запустится "как есть"?

Есть данные, которые сохраняются в файлах, слышал, что на андройде они записываются/читаются отлично, чем на win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо никаких отличий в коде практически нет - управление только, наверное. Если ты привязывался к нажатию кнопок, то на телефонах ты кнопок уже не имеешь.

Есть отличия в подходе к созданию интерфейса - разного рода менюх и контролов на экране заменяющих кнопки. Возможно добавление поддержки свайпов и бла бла бла.

Ну и прийдется оптимизировать все значительно усерднее, само собой. Т.к. ресурсов на мобильных телефонах значительно меньше чем на компьютерах. Но это ты уже по ходу дела сам увидишь уже после того как решишь какие телефоны поддерживать минимально.

Так же нельзя использовать полноценные шейдеры - нужно использовать их мобильные аналоги - они значительно "проще" и быстрее работают - но это, снова таки, вопрос оптимизации.

По поводу билда под айос - тебе для этого нужно иметь мак с установленным XCode под рукой. С самого юнити под виндой просто так ничего не выйдет.

Вобщем пробуй - там по ходу дела разберешся.